# EWS Managed API 2, setting sender/from display name

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api, exchange-server-2003

I'm trying to set the display name of the sender on an e-mail. I have tried to set both the Sender and From attributes of the EmailMessage but neither seem to change the display name - the e-mail always arrives with the actual name associated with the Exchange account.

Is there a way to successfully change the name that is displayed without changing the name of the account or changing to another account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No when the message arrives in the Target Mailbox the Information store will resolve the Address back to the Native (EX) Address of the recipient which will mean if you look at the address in the Client it will always appear as the primary. This is the way Exchange has always worked and can't be controlled.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly, you can't use an Exchange e-mail address like "no_reply@company_name.com" to sent mails where display name is "Support", "Notification" or "Newsletter" - the display name will always end being the original associated with the no_replay account?

Comment: It will always be resolved back to the Primary SMTP address of the sender. If your worried about people replying then you can set a replyTo to something different.

Comment: Ah no, the no_reply address was just an example.

Comment: @GlenScales If i'm understand right. In the Send on behalf case, such as recipient receive like : John on behalf of Jonas, now i can not change the display name of this too . Is that right?